# Rails keep using old version of my images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, erb

I had a few images on my website that were over 1MB so I compressed them and uploaded them to the server (replaced them using same names, in app/assets). I also deleted the images that were previously generated in /public/assets.

In my index.html.erb I use the image like `header/logo.png`

However in my browser, the image name is always for example `logo-d19a42b2a0872961c14523505539a29c.png` (same name as before) and the same 1MB size as the previous image. I cleared cache / cookies.
Weirdly, on the server if I do `find . -name "logo-d19a42b2a0872961c14523505539a29c.png"` there is nothing found.

Is that normal rails behavior? What should I do to fix that?

Comment: The `d19a42b...` suffix is called a "digest".  See [The Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Comment: Once I've made a change in the config/application.rb file, how do I restart the config?

Comment: To reload the config, you need to restart the app.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may have a web server or reverse proxy that that is responsible for serving static content.  Do you have nginx or something else in front of the rails app?  You may need to restart that server or flush the cache there.

Comment: Thanks -- I'll check that. About the names with digest however, how do I get rid of it? I tried putting config.assets.digest = false in the config files but it still doesnt work. Should I reload something?

Comment: In rails, you should be able to set
    `config.assets.digest = false`  though there have apparently been some defects floating around with that.  You may need to set  precompile assets off as well.  If you don't want to do that, check out this this gem https://github.com/alexspeller/non-stupid-digest-assets